# Problems speeding up my Calendar-retrieving script by putting it in an local array in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm writing code to track my hours, retrieving calendar items from Google Calendar and writing it into Google Sheets.

I'm already using a batch array to speedup the process, but I feel I could make it even faster. I've tried to use the map-function (see dashed-out code below, created from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=985XJOeigpA)) but that did not work out.

My code:

```js
function getCalendarEvents() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email@domain.nl"); 
  var eind = new Date;
  eind.setDate(eind.getDate()+1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("1/1/2022"), eind);
  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(3, 1, lr,14).clearContent();
  
//  var sd = events.map(function(r){ return [r[0],[2]]} );
//  ss.getRange(3, 2, sd.length,sd[0].length).setValues(sd);

  for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++) {
    
    var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
    var des = events[i].getDescription();
    var rec = events[i].isRecurringEvent();
    var cre = events[i].getDateCreated();
    var upd = events[i].getLastUpdated();
    var own = events[i].getCreators();
    
    ss.getRange(i+3, 2).setValue(sd);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 2).setNumberFormat("ddd   d-m-yyyy");
    ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setValue(ed);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setNumberFormat("h:mm");
    ss.getRange(i+3, 9).setValue(title);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 10).setValue(des);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 11).setValue(cre);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 12).setValue(upd);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 13).setValue(rec);
    ss.getRange(i+3, 14).setValue(own);

  }  
}
```

How can I put the code with the "setValue" snippets (within the loop) in a batch array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not tested but could work)

```
function getCalendarEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email@domain.nl"); 
  var eind = new Date;
  eind.setDate(eind.getDate()+1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("1/1/2022"), eind);
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(3, 1, lr,14).clearContent();
  var result = []
  events.forEach(e => {
    result.push([e.getStartTime(),
                e.getTitle(),
                e.getEndTime(),
                e.getDescription(),
                e.isRecurringEvent(),
                e.getDateCreated(),
                e.getLastUpdated(),
                e.getCreators()])
  })
  ss.getRange(3,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed WAY faster and it writes down the results indeed... however the results are written to the wrong columns, and the dates in the wrong format too. Can I target each "result.push" action to the right column, and in the right date format like in my original code?

Comment: What do you have in columns D, E and so on? I think if you want something a bit faster you should rearrange the columns to make them closer to each other.

Comment: Format dates as follows `Utilities.formatDate(e.getEndTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), ""ddd   d-m-yyyy"")` but take care of your script timezone (I will show you if you encounter issue)

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you SO very much for your help! Of course you were right: rearranging columns was the best option. In fact, I added a worksheet called "Source data" to where the data from your script is written to. In the sheet "Data" I'm now pulling data from "Source data" giving me the freedom to arrange columns as I want. Now, my script runs in 3 seconds, in stead of 30 :-)